# flashplugin vs. PepperFlash

Tags: manjaro, browser, adobe-flash, plugin, flash

I'm totally confused about the installation in my Manjaro. I remember that months ago I was just happy to see Flash-videos in my Vivaldi.

So here is what I have (I removed some obvious false positives):

```
[root@runlikehell ~]# find / -iname "*pepper*"
/opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash
/home/sjngm/.config/vivaldi/Default/Pepper Data

[root@runlikehell ~]# find / -iname "*flash*"
/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so
/usr/lib/kde4/kcm_adobe_flash_player.so
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libflashlo.so
/usr/share/licenses/flashplugin
/usr/share/mime/application/vnd.adobe.flash.movie.xml
/usr/share/kde4/services/kcm_adobe_flash_player.desktop
/usr/share/applications/flash-player-properties.desktop
/usr/bin/flash-var
/usr/bin/flash-player-properties
/var/lib/pacman/local/flashplugin-25.0.0.171-1
/var/cache/pacman/pkg/flashplugin-25.0.0.171-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
/var/cache/pacman/pkg/flashplugin-25.0.0.127-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
/var/cache/pacman/pkg/flashplugin-25.0.0.148-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
/opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash
/opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so
/home/sjngm/.macromedia/Flash_Player
/home/sjngm/.macromedia/Flash_Player/macromedia.com/support/flashplayer
/home/sjngm/.macromedia/Flash_Player/#SharedObjects/XV4QLATD/static.cdn-ec.viddler.com/flash
/home/sjngm/.adobe/Flash_Player
/home/sjngm/.config/vivaldi/Default/Pepper Data/Shockwave Flash
/home/sjngm/.config/vivaldi/Default/Pepper Data/Shockwave Flash/WritableRoot/#SharedObjects/CDJUJ6XP/macromedia.com/support/flashplayer
/home/sjngm/.config/vivaldi/Default/Pepper Data/Shockwave Flash/WritableRoot/#SharedObjects/CDJUJ6XP/de.chaturbate.com/static/javascript-flash-cookies
/home/sjngm/.config/vivaldi/Default/Pepper Data/Shockwave Flash/WritableRoot/#SharedObjects/CDJUJ6XP/ss.phncdn.com/html5player/videoPlayer/oldFlash
[root@runlikehell ~]#
```

If I go to http://get.adobe.com/en/flashplayer/about/ it tells me that I have version 22,0,0,209 (sic) installed. However, I can see that Octopi shows a `pepper-flash` 25.0.0.171-1 (the icon shows that I haven't installed it yet) in YAOURT and a `flashplugin` 25.0.0.171-1 (installed).

From what I remember Vivaldi needs the Pepper Flash to work, but I can't remember how I made it work back then. Shame on me... Also I don't know where Vivaldi tries to find the plug-in.

Do I still have a correct installation (just because I can see videos is no proof to me)? Should I install YAOURT's `pepper-flash`? Do I need to do further steps after installing this? Should I remove anything from my current installation?

I'd really appreciate if somebody can line out the steps I need to take to move to an automated update of that plug-in via Octopi/pacman as version 22.x is just plain old and I obviously have troubles to keep up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was way too curious to wait any longer ;)

I fooled around with `/opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so` and noticed that it really was the library Vivaldi uses. I decided to install `pepper-flash` and the library is now in `/usr/lib/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so`. I removed the original location and everything is running fine so far, the Adobe site tells me that I'm using an up-to-date version...